# fancyhdr and extramarks packages: incorrect header when chapter ends page

Tags: conditionals, fancyhdr

I have an encountered a problem with the `\fancyhdr` and `\extramarks` packages. When a chapter ends on a page, it puts the wrong chapter number. However, if a new chapter starts on that page, it renders it correctly. Can someone help me understand why `\fancyhdr` does this? I have attached a MWE.

```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    
% % Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% % Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \needspace{2.4\baselineskip}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\centering\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\space\themychapter\space}}% Center the chapter title with bold chapter number
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  }
\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  % Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}
}  

\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\leftmark:\firstleftxmark—–\lastleftxmark} % if equal
{\rightmark:\firstrightxmark ––\leftmark:\lastleftxmark}} % if not equal 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\mymarks} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}

\begin{document}

\mychapter{1}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]
\bibver{6} \lipsum[6]

\mychapter{2}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]

\mychapter{3}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]


\mychapter{4}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]


\mychapter{5}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]
\bibver{6} \lipsum[6]

\mychapter{6}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

**This is the new position of the command, but it still gives the wrong number when a chapter ends on a page and begins at the top of a new page.**

As can be seen from this example, on certain pages, it works okay, but if the last `\bibver` ends a page or ends on the top of page, the header shows the following chapter. I don't think it is a logic error, since it gives the right response in every other case——unless I have overlooked something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your \markboth command is too early, it can be on the previous page.

Comment: also your `\centering` will not center the text as it is missing `\par` and `\stepcounter` should be `\refstepcounter` if you want to `\label`  the chapter. Why not use `\chapter` ?

Comment: I will edit the `\mychapter` to reflect your comments, @DavidCarlisle. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: That does not seem to have fixed the problem. I still have edge cases where the chapter or verse is not correct.

Comment: You need to be able to provide a minimal example that gives the problem. Additionally please make sure your example does not depend on things others do not have access to, for example special fonts.

Comment: Thanks, @daleif. I have updated the MWE.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the edge cases where a chapter ends at the bottom of a page, it is necessary to use conditional logic to address the case where the top number is bigger than the bottom number.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    
% % Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% % Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \needspace{2.4\baselineskip}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\centering\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\space\themychapter\space}}% Center the chapter title with bold chapter number
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  }
\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  % Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}
}  

\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\rightmark}{\leftmark} \AND \firstrightxmark > \lastleftxmark}{%
    \lastleftmark:1––\lastleftxmark % Code if both conditions are true
  }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\rightmark}{\leftmark}}{%
      \lastleftmark:\firstrightxmark ––\lastleftxmark % Code if only the first condition is true
    }{%
      \firstrightmark:\firstrightxmark ––\lastleftmark:\lastleftxmark % Code if neither condition is true
    }
  }
}
 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\mymarks} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}

\begin{document}

\mychapter{1}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]
\bibver{6} \lipsum[6]

\mychapter{2}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]

\mychapter{3}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]


\mychapter{4}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]


\mychapter{5}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]
\bibver{5} \lipsum[5]
\bibver{6} \lipsum[6]

\mychapter{6}
\bibver{1} \lipsum[1]
\bibver{2} \lipsum[2]
\bibver{3} \lipsum[3]
\bibver{4} \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```